# In if statement double use $ (smarty)

Tags: php, if-statement, smarty

Question about smarty if statement.

I have create a counter and i need the value of the counter in a if statement.
The counter looks like this:

```
{assign var="counter" value=1}
```

It looks like this:

```
{if $task.check_counter == "on"} checked {/if}
```

It have to looks like:

```
{if $task.check_1 == "on"} checked {/if}
```

Is this possible?

**UPDATE:**
Part of the code:

```
{assign var="counter" value=1}                              
    {foreach from=$service item=sert}
        {if $sert.parent_id == $task.task_id}  
            <tr>
                <td>{$sert.name}</td>
                <td>{$address_detail.start}</td>
                <td style="text-align: center;">
                    <div>
                        <input  type="checkbox" 
                                class="icheck" name="c_{$counter}" 
                                id="icheck_{$counter}"
                                {if $task.check_$counter == "on"} checked {/if} >
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            {assign var="counter" value=$counter + 1}
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: `{if $task.check_{$counter} == "on"}` have you tried anything to get it working already? If you have - add what you tried so people don't suggest the obvious stuff...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99 times out of 100 where you are using "variable variables", you should actually be defining an array.

If instead of dynamically naming your items as `check_1`, `check_2`, etc, you defined an array of items called `check_list`, you could just do this: `{$task.check_list.$counter}`

Note that you can even do this with form fields, as PHP will turn fields like `<input name="task[check][1]" />` into appropriate arrays when it processes the form submission.

That said, since this particular case isn't actually a variable name but an array key within the `$task` array, you can define the whole key as a dynamic string, and look up using that:

```
{assign var=array_key value='check_'|cat:$counter}
{if $task.$array_key == "on"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this;

Assign your smarty variable like;

```
$smarty->assign('counter', 1);
```

Then try this

```
{if $task.check_$smarty->get_template_vars('counter') == "on"} checked {/if}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Already tried it, but it returns a blank page.

Comment: Edited the answer. Please chk

Comment: Same result. Blank page! :(